# Ecto.Datetime get 15 minutes ago

Tags: elixir, ecto

`Ecto.DateTime.utc` returns current datetime.

How can I create `Ecto.DateTime` for 15 minutes ago?

Comment: There's [`ago`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html#ago/2), though you can't invoke it directly (it's meant to be used in a `where` clause for example).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Get the time using `:erlang.universaltime` (Ecto uses this for `Ecto.DateTime.utc/0`), convert to gregorian seconds using `:calendar`, subtract 15 * 60, convert back to an Erlang Time tuple, and cast back to `Ecto.DateTime`:

```
iex(1)> utc = :erlang.universaltime |> :calendar.datetime_to_gregorian_seconds
63638236105
iex(2)> fifteen_minutes_ago = (utc - 15 * 60) |> :calendar.gregorian_seconds_to_datetime |> Ecto.DateTime.cast!
#Ecto.DateTime<2016-08-12 15:33:25>
```

Edit: a pipeline might look better here:

```
:erlang.universaltime
|> :calendar.datetime_to_gregorian_seconds
|> Kernel.-(15 * 60)
|> :calendar.gregorian_seconds_to_datetime
|> Ecto.DateTime.cast!
|> IO.inspect
```

Same output as before.

Comment: It's working, thanks! But it's kinda long function chain here. Let's wait for shorter implementations, maybe? P.S. I'm not surprised that timex has been created ;)

Comment: Yep, it's long, but I don't think there's a shorter solution without using another library. I added a solution with a pipe chain that might look a little better. It would be great if someone posts a shorter solution though!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone landing here in 2023, Elixir's DateTime module has an `add()` function which does accept negative numbers, so you could do something like:

```
DateTime.add(DateTime.utc_now(), -15, :minute)
```

See [the hexdocs](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.15.6/DateTime.html#add/4) for the full definition and options.